# How can files and classes be renamed in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

How do I rename files and classes (declaration, implementation and uses) in [Qt Creator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator) 2.0?

I can't find such feature in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such feature in Qt Creator :(

This is what you can do:

To rename files:

- close your project
- rename files in Windows Explorer or some other tool
- open project
- update *.pro file, list *.h files in *headers*, *.CPP files in *sources*, *.ui files in *forms*
- update all *.ccp files in the #include section to include proper files

To change class names you can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> feature that changes class names in header files and source files.

Comment: Just right click on needed name and follow Refactor - > Rename Symbol Under Cursor
or just press Ctrl+Shift+R, after selecting that class name

Answer (score 2):

If you also want to rename a form and along with its class, you have to edit your `name.ui` file and change the `widget name` and `class` to the new corresponding value.

You also need to rename some things in your `name.h` file.

```
namespace Ui {
    class NewValueHere;
}

private:
    Ui::NewValueHere* mUI;
```

In your `name.cpp` file you also have to adjust the call of creating your `mUI`.

`mUI(new Ui::NewValueHere)`

Answer (score 2):

Personnally I needed to do something more.

I renamed my class "Form" to "MainWindow", and I had to go in the directory "build-yourproject...-Debug\ui_mainwindow.h" and replace every "Form" with "MainWindow" (Ctrl+f) and then it worked.

EDIT: This was a manual solution that changes a file that is re-loaded at every build, so this change is automatically lost. The right solution is to go in Qt Creator and in the upper-right corner, under the name "Object", you should have the name of your class, that is what you need to change.